# Using push_back for vector<vector<string>> correctly with a for & while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, vector, delimiter

Basically I have image coordinates in the form of strings. I have a vector of those 2 strings and and I am parsing it using some delimiters. The parsing is being done correctly and the first push_back to the vector"<"string">" vector1 as well. But when I apply a push_back again after the while loop to store vector1 in a vector"<"vector"<"string">>" vector2 (as I want to build multiple vector"<"Point">"s later on) the result of vector2 has repeated vector1[0] 2 times and answer is 123456123456789101112. And I want 123456789101112.

What am I doing wrong?
For the question purposes I built the sample **vector"<"string">" result;** myself but I am getting it from another function in my original code.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    size_t beg, pos = 0;
    string s = "[[[1 2]] [[3 4]] [[5 6]]]";
    string t = "[[[7 8]] [[9 10]] [[11 12]]]";
    vector<string> resultvec;
    resultvec.push_back(s);
    resultvec.push_back(t);

    string const delims{ "[] " };

    vector<string> vector1;
    vector<vector<string>> vector2;

    for(int i=0; i<resultvec.size(); i++)
    {
        while ((beg = resultvec[i].find_first_not_of(delims, pos)) != string::npos)
        {
            pos = resultvec[i].find_first_of(delims, beg + 1);
            {
                vector1.push_back(resultvec[i].substr(beg, pos - beg));
                //cout << resultvec[i].substr(beg, pos - beg) << endl;
            }
        }
            
        beg = 0;
        pos = 0;
        vector2.push_back(vector1);
    }
    cout<<"==========vector1==============="<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<vector1.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<vector1[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"==========vector2==============="<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vector2.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < vector2[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout<<vector2[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
    }
```

Output

```
    ===========vector1================
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8  
    9
    10
    11
    12
    ===========vector2==============
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
```

and I want

```
    ===========vector1================
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8  
    9
    10
    11
    12
    ===========vector2==============
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
```

Comment: `result2` is used without being declared. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program, one line at a time, and monitor what's in all these variables and vectors, and how they change after executing each line of your program (as reported by your debugger) what did you see, and when did the expected results started to differ from your expected results?

Comment: `resulvec` and `r` are also used without declarations.

Comment: @MikeCAT I updated

Comment: Are you hastily typing in code while posting the question?  You should take a step back, make sure the final code you actually post compiles and produces the results you're claiming, instead of trying to do on-line, real-time edits.

Comment: You should move `vector2.push_back(vector1);` after the loop and have it be executed only once. Otherwise, `vector2` will have multiple elements and it will make the contents from `vector1` and `vector2` differ because printing `vector2` means at least printing all elements of `vector1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first grance, it looks like you forgot to clear `vector1` before each iteration.

To clear `vector1`, add call to `clear()` here:

```
    for(int i=0; i<resulvec.size(); i++)
    {
        vector1.clear(); // add call to clear() here
        while ((beg = resultvec[i].find_first_not_of(delims, pos)) != string::npos)
        {
            // omit
        }
            
        beg = 0;
        pos = 0;
        vector2.push_back(vector1);
    }
```

But this is actually wrong and now the output will be:

```
    ===========vector1================
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
    ===========vector2==============
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
```

To obtain the wanted output, you should push `vector1` to `vector2` only once to match the output from `vector1` and `vector2`.

It will be like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<resulvec.size(); i++)
    {
        while ((beg = resultvec[i].find_first_not_of(delims, pos)) != string::npos)
        {
            // omit
        }
            
        beg = 0;
        pos = 0;
        // move this
        // vector2.push_back(vector1);
    }
    // here
    vector2.push_back(vector1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is not quite pasted right, but from what I gleem I think you are accumulating `vector1` inside the inner loop, adding that to `vector2` in the outer loop, but never starting over for `vector1` (or is it `r`?).  You keep appending to `vector1` which still contains the previous values.

Add a `vector1.clear()` call at the top of the outer loop.

Comment: OK, then my reading is correct.  vector2 will contain successive snapshots of the growing vector1.

Comment: Umm 1 more thing. Now the vector1 output is always 789101112. Although now I dont need vector1 but still for the knowledge how to correct it?